# data not accessible outside of subscription function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-services

I am passing data between components onload. When the component receives the information within the subscribe function it is able to use the data and do whatever with it, so a console.log works fine, so it is clearly receiving it, but immediately outside of the subscribe function the information is unaccessible and is undefined. So I can't run a console.log or do anything with the information. In the html, it says that it is undefined as well.

The component.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { User } from '../User';
import { AccountInfo } from './../AccountInfo';
import { LoginService } from './../login.service';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

public user: User;
public subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private loginService: LoginService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.getMessage().subscribe(data =>
    {
      this.user = data;
      console.log(this.user.vendorname);
     });

    console.log(this.user.vendorname);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
    //Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.
    }  

  }
```

relevant section of html

```
<h1>Welcome {{user.vendorname}}</h1>
```

Comment: It's not that "outside" of it it's unaccessible, it's just that it's **asyncronous**. you should use an *ngIf in your <h1> tag, providing: `<h1 *ngIf="user !== undefined">{{user.vendorname}}</h1>`. Angular will do the rest for you: as long as the subscribe function is called **at least once** and as long as **data is defined** and as long as **data is a User instance** it will work properly. You are receiving undefined in the second log because by the time it is logged it has not been defined yet, since the subscribe callback is asyncronous. Alternatively, use the `?` after `user` (nullable)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. that's how `async` functions work. The thing you pass into the `subscribe` function is another function.

```
data => {
  this.user = data;
  console.log(this.user.vendorname);
}
```

This will be called once the `getMessage()` has received answer from your server. Any statements after the `subscribe` will be called immediately, and that's why `this.user.vendorname` is still undefined when you try to log it there.

If you are receiving an error in your `html` you should use the safe navigation operator (`?.`):

```
<h1>Welcome {{user?.vendorname}}</h1>
```

Comment: Deserved +1 for the safe navigation operator, clever choice :).

Comment: So there is no way to access the information in subscribe outside of the subscribe function? All functions using the user object must be done inside the subscribe function?

Comment: Also I changed it to {{user?.vendorname}} and while I don't get an error message it still leaves the vendorname area blank. It just says "Welcome" instead of "Welcome WhateverVendorNameIs"

Comment: You are right, everything needs to be done in there. And I guess you are not getting the right object, or are not parsing the `JSON`, or it's `vendorName` instead of `vendorname`